# glassfish v4 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, glassfish, javafx-2

I am still trying to make JavaFX-samples-2.2.25 DataApp work for me. I started from scratch again by follow its instruction and didn't change/add anything. I got the following glassfish server error:

```
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB CumulativeLiveSalesFacadeREST: [java:global/DataAppServer/CumulativeLiveSalesFacadeREST, java:global/DataAppServer/CumulativeLiveSalesFacadeREST!com.javafx.experiments.dataapp.server.service.CumulativeLiveSalesFacadeREST]
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB RegionFacadeREST: [java:global/DataAppServer/RegionFacadeREST!com.javafx.experiments.dataapp.server.service.RegionFacadeREST, java:global/DataAppServer/RegionFacadeREST]
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB LiveSalesListFacadeREST: [java:global/DataAppServer/LiveSalesListFacadeREST!com.javafx.experiments.dataapp.server.service.LiveSalesListFacadeREST, java:global/DataAppServer/LiveSalesListFacadeREST]
INFO:   WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)
WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
WARNING:   Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
INFO:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Marking servlet ServletAdaptor as unavailable
SEVERE:   WebModule[/DataAppServer]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1761)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1381)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5670)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5912)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
```

I need to do any extra configuration or installation?

**EDIT:**

The glassfish is installed with NetBeans 3.7.1 IDE.

Comment: Did you download the full version of Glassfish?

Comment: The one I installed came with NetBeans 3.7.1. I also downloaded one. The size of the glassfish in use is much bigger than the one I download separately. I cannot find that missing class in all jersey jar files.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and according to [this](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18811), you need to change the servlet class from com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer to org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer in the web.xml config file.

Comment: Now I get `org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Injector] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.servlet.GuiceContainer(Injector)]`

Comment: I brought this sample app up to date so that it could be run it without much of a hassle with a recent web server, latest APIs, etc. The project can be found here in case anyone is interested: [link](https://github.com/p-smith/javafx-dataapp-sample)

Answer (score 1):

I used netbeans 7.4 with glassfish 4.0 to run the dataapp samples 2.2.45, 2.2.25 should be the same thing also. I had the same problem. What I do is use to had those two jars in the DataappClient (jersey-bundles-1.17.1 and jersey-client-1.17.1). Since the Glassfish 4.0 is "buggy", I used Glassfish-3.1.2.2 instead of 4.0.