# Glassfish give errror in popup that deploy is failing=null but when i see eclipse console it deploy my project successfully, why?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

first of all i am newbie to java ee 7, i am using eclipse kepler and glassfish 4.0 .
The problem is when i run my project then a popup window opens saying Problem occured, cannot deply project, deploy is failing=null , meanwhile i see the eclipse console, there it says that ptoject deployed successfully. I am pasting my console log here, please figure it out why i am facing this problem, here is my console log:-

```
    2014-04-26T08:05:48.071+0530|INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
    2014-04-26T08:05:48.074+0530|INFO: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
    2014-04-26T08:05:48.440+0530|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
    2014-04-26T08:05:48.451+0530|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
    2014-04-26T08:05:48.474+0530|INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.151+0530|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 36ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.183+0530|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.194+0530|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.359+0530|INFO: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.410+0530|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 11ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.419+0530|INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.937+0530|INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [72]], State = [READY]
    2014-04-26T08:05:49.938+0530|INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [156]], State = [READY]
    2014-04-26T08:05:50.322+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references

2014-04-26T08:19:46.029+0530|INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
2014-04-26T08:19:46.043+0530|INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
2014-04-26T08:19:46.047+0530|INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2014-04-26T08:19:46.099+0530|INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
2014-04-26T08:19:46.404+0530|INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2014-04-26T08:19:46.415+0530|INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2014-04-26T08:19:46.419+0530|INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2014-04-26T08:19:46.450+0530|INFO: Created virtual server server
2014-04-26T08:19:46.453+0530|INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
2014-04-26T08:19:46.747+0530|INFO: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2014-04-26T08:19:46.751+0530|INFO: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2014-04-26T08:19:47.629+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:47.803+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:48.209+0530|INFO: Loading application [hello2] at [/hello2]
2014-04-26T08:19:48.215+0530|INFO: Loading application hello2 done in 3,142 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:48.225+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:48.450+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:48.460+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:48.582+0530|INFO: WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)
2014-04-26T08:19:49.103+0530|INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2014-04-26T08:19:50.393+0530|WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-04-26T08:19:50.394+0530|WARNING: Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
2014-04-26T08:19:51.466+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/bookmarks'
2014-04-26T08:19:53.256+0530|INFO: Loading application [bookmarks] at [/bookmarks]
2014-04-26T08:19:53.257+0530|INFO: Loading application bookmarks done in 5,042 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:53.264+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:53.311+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:53.316+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:53.738+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/guessnumber-jsf'
2014-04-26T08:19:54.059+0530|INFO: Loading application [guessnumber-jsf] at [/guessnumber-jsf]
2014-04-26T08:19:54.060+0530|INFO: Loading application guessnumber-jsf done in 802 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:54.067+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:54.109+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:54.114+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:54.466+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/hello1-rlc'
2014-04-26T08:19:54.792+0530|INFO: Processing resource library contract mapping for url-pattern: /reply/*
2014-04-26T08:19:54.795+0530|INFO: Added contract: reply for url-pattern: /reply/*
2014-04-26T08:19:54.798+0530|INFO: Processing resource library contract mapping for url-pattern: *
2014-04-26T08:19:54.800+0530|INFO: Added contract: hello for url-pattern: *
2014-04-26T08:19:54.871+0530|INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/hello1-rlc/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2014-04-26T08:19:54.891+0530|INFO: Loading application [hello1-rlc] at [/hello1-rlc]
2014-04-26T08:19:54.893+0530|INFO: Loading application hello1-rlc done in 832 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:54.898+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:54.939+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:54.942+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:55.587+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/reservation'
2014-04-26T08:19:55.892+0530|INFO: Loading application [reservation] at [/reservation]
2014-04-26T08:19:55.895+0530|INFO: Loading application reservation done in 1,002 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:55.900+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:55.940+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:55.943+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:56.262+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/hello1'
2014-04-26T08:19:56.537+0530|INFO: Loading application [hello1] at [/hello1]
2014-04-26T08:19:56.539+0530|INFO: Loading application hello1 done in 643 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:56.540+0530|SEVERE: Application previously deployed is not at its original location any more: file:/home/nimbus/glassfish4/docs/javaee-tutorial/examples/case-studies/dukes-bookstore/target/dukes-bookstore/
2014-04-26T08:19:56.549+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:56.598+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:56.602+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:19:56.944+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/MyFirstWebApp'
2014-04-26T08:19:57.226+0530|INFO: Monitoring jndi:/server/MyFirstWebApp/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2014-04-26T08:19:57.245+0530|INFO: Loading application [MyFirstWebApp] at [/MyFirstWebApp]
2014-04-26T08:19:57.246+0530|INFO: Loading application MyFirstWebApp done in 704 ms
2014-04-26T08:19:57.379+0530|INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (2,689ms), startup services(13,436ms), total(16,125ms)
2014-04-26T08:19:57.750+0530|INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
2014-04-26T08:19:58.612+0530|INFO: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi
2014-04-26T08:19:58.753+0530|INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 4ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7,676]
2014-04-26T08:19:58.821+0530|INFO: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@17ead3d as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@19d0d9c.
2014-04-26T08:20:02.278+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:02.565+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:02.800+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:02.854+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:02.855+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:02.857+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:03.164+0530|INFO: visiting unvisited references
2014-04-26T08:20:06.269+0530|INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b
2014-04-26T08:20:07.181+0530|INFO: file:/home/nimbus/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/timetablemgmt/WEB-INF/classes/_timetablemgmt login successful
2014-04-26T08:20:07.396+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ScheduleBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/ScheduleBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/ScheduleBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.ScheduleBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.517+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB CourseBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/CourseBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/CourseBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.CourseBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.532+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB DetailBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/DetailBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.DetailBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/DetailBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.546+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB FloorBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/FloorBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.FloorBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/FloorBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.561+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB DepartmentBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/DepartmentBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.DepartmentBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/DepartmentBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.576+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB BatchBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/BatchBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.BatchBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/BatchBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.590+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB DetailBatchBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/DetailBatchBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.DetailBatchBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/DetailBatchBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.604+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB AddressTypeBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/AddressTypeBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.AddressTypeBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/AddressTypeBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.618+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB QualificationBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/QualificationBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/QualificationBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.QualificationBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.633+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB UserBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/UserBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/UserBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.UserBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.648+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB FacultyBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/FacultyBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/FacultyBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.FacultyBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.662+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB BuildingBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/BuildingBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.BuildingBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/BuildingBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.694+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB RoomBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/RoomBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/RoomBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.RoomBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.710+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB QualificationTypeBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/QualificationTypeBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/QualificationTypeBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.QualificationTypeBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.724+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ContactBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/ContactBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/ContactBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.ContactBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.778+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TimetableBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/TimetableBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/TimetableBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.TimetableBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.793+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SemesterBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/SemesterBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/SemesterBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.SemesterBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.809+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB BranchBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/BranchBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.BranchBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/BranchBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.825+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB RoleBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/RoleBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.RoleBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/RoleBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.840+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB FacultySubjectBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/FacultySubjectBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/FacultySubjectBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.FacultySubjectBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.856+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SubjectBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/SubjectBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/SubjectBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.SubjectBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.869+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SectionBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/SectionBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/SectionBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.SectionBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.884+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB DesignationBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/DesignationBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/DesignationBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.DesignationBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.900+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ContactTypeBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/ContactTypeBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/ContactTypeBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.ContactTypeBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.915+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB SesionBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/SesionBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/SesionBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.SesionBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.928+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB RoomTypeBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/RoomTypeBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/RoomTypeBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.RoomTypeBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.941+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ScheduleTypeBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/ScheduleTypeBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/ScheduleTypeBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.ScheduleTypeBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:07.955+0530|INFO: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB AddressBean: [java:global/timetablemgmt/AddressBean!in.nimbusinfocom.schedulemgmt.dao.AddressBean, java:global/timetablemgmt/AddressBean]
2014-04-26T08:20:08.536+0530|INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context '/timetablemgmt'
2014-04-26T08:20:08.879+0530|INFO: Loading application [timetablemgmt] at [/timetablemgmt]
2014-04-26T08:20:09.019+0530|INFO: timetablemgmt was successfully deployed in 6,978 milliseconds.
```

I tried a lot but cannot figure out the problem. Please tell me where i am doing wrong.
Glassfish doing this for all my projects in eclipse.

I installed glassfish manually and then i set glassfish path in eclipse. It was working fine but from last 3 days it is giving same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if [the following](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20564) applies to you. There's also [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284534/glassfish-v4-classnotfoundexception) with a seemingly similar problem.

Comment: Thanks but i installed glassfish manually so i think the post in your comment will not help me.